# Protected .pyd not working with debug mode in c# sharp console application

Tags: c#, python-3.x, console-application

I have converted  .py  to  .pyd with help of nuitka pcakge  in python that have simple addtion function. Now i protect reverse eng using pcGuard software latest version. Now, i call this protected .pyd in c# console application without debugging it will work but with debugging not working

I need Solution to protect the .pyd file and working with debug mode on c# console application